# Open interval by summation

Tags: summation

$A = \{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{5^k}\}$ where $ a_k = [0,1,2,3,4]$ can the set $A$ contain an open interval? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: Suppose the problem said $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{10^k},$ and the $a_k$ all belonged to $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}.$ Could you solve it then?

Hint 2: For your problem, use base $5$ instead of base $10.$

Comment: I want elements of base 10, how would that be achieved?

Comment: So every open interval in base 10, could be made in base 5, and that interval would still be open. It is like the whole real number line is written in base 5 form. Am I right?

Comment: Real numbers are what they are. It doesn't matter how you write them--base 10, base 5, or something else. In the same way, there's no such thing as an open interval "in base 5" or "in base 10"; an open interval is just an open interval of real numbers, and you can write those real numbers in any convenient way. (The expression $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{10^k}$ is basically a decimal, and the expression $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{5^k}$ is the same thing but in base 5. So base 5 is convenient for thinking about your problem. The sums can be viewed as just ways of writing real numbers.)

Comment: But you can't write 9 in base 5. It would be 14 in base 5.  So when one looks at the real line, is it just a collection of things, which can be represented in different ways? I am sorry, all this time I have looked at real line in only base 10.

Comment: Yes, the same point on the number line that you label as $"\!9\!"$ in base $10$ is labeled as $"\!14\!"$ in base $9.$  But those are just names; they represent the same number (essentially in different codes).  It's like writing "nine" in English, "neuf" in French, or "nueve" in Spanish; they're just different ways of writing the same number. (In your example, though, you want to look at decimals, or the equivalent in base $5$ -- numbers between $0$ and $1.)$

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last thing, the question is equivalent to whether I can write all Real numbers between 0,1 if I were to use 0-9 digits and 10 in denominator. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly -- those are just decimals, and your problem is essentially the same thing in that you're writing all the numbers between 0 and 1 as a "decimal" in base 5, using the digits 0 through 4.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** An element of $A$ is a number (written in base $5$). Which numbers are achieved?